Can Survey123 copy a submitted record (on an existing feature class) to another table/feature layer?
I currently have a Survey123 Connect survey form that references an existing feature layer hosted on our Portal. Basic workflow is: when someone populates a survey with a project's ID, it prepopulates that record's data into the survey from the existing feature associated with that ID. Then, they can overwrite any of those attributes within the existing feature layer by submission of the survey. This works fine, however, it doesn't really allow for a paper trail.
I would also like to be able to flag records that were updated (had a survey submitted), or better yet copy the submitted survey record to another feature layer. My concern is if the primary feature layer is corrupted in some way, I wouldn't want to lose all the edits that were submitted by another department, and have a reference backed up. Wouldn't this be possible by connecting the survey to another layer on the 'Settings' tab of the XLSForm? Or perform some kind of repeat function?
I thought this was doable, but can't really find a solid workflow outline on it out there. Other workflow ideas are welcome!

I once used a trigger on the target enterprise geodatabase table to populate new features.

I recently had to work this out. The workaround that I found was to have a Python script running on a server that periodically checks for new submitted records. If a new record is found then it is selected, copied, and appended to the target feature class you want to store these features in. Definitely not ideal, but it does work.
